# How to optimize nested serializer custom update method

Tags: django, performance, django-rest-framework

I'm writing a serializer that points to a nested serializer and as the documentation explains it is necesary to write custom create and update methods so that nested serializers could be writable. The way I'm doing this is next:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.attr1 = validated_data.get('attr1', instance)
    instance.attr2 = validated_data.get('attr2', instance)
    instance.attr3 = validated_data.get('attr3', instance)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

but the instance has 26 attributes. The question is. Is there a way of improving this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
for attr in ['attr1','attr2', ......]:
    setattr(instance, attr, validated_data.get(attr, instance))
```

Comment: I suppose that's gonna be the solution due to the dynamic attributes django provides to classes, so, huge thanks mate.

Comment: @user3347778 you're welcome.